# Toast is showing twice repeatedly

Tags: java, android, toast

When I am pressing Refresh button then toast is showing up twice repeatedly.

I am implementing toast only once.
Is there anything to do with adapter?

Here is the code -

```
public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<EarthquakeDetails>> {

    public static final String USGS_URL;
    public static ArrayList<EarthquakeDetails> earthquakes;
    private boolean refreshed = false;
    ListView earthquakeListView;
    EarthquakeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);
        earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, EarthquakeActivity.this).forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<EarthquakeDetails>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Builder uriBuilder;
        <building of url>
        for (int i= 0; i < Integer.parseInt(limit); i++) {
            maps.add(null);
        }
        return new EarthquakeAsyncTaskLoader(EarthquakeActivity.this, uriBuilder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<EarthquakeDetails>> loader, ArrayList<EarthquakeDetails> data) {
        earthquakes = data;
        adapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(EarthquakeActivity.this, earthquakes);
        if (!isConnected || earthquakes == null) {
           <do something>
        } else if (earthquakes.size() < 1 || earthquakes.get(0) == null) {
            <do something else>
        } else {
            earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            if(refreshed){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.list).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.went_wrong).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        findViewById(R.id.refresh).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        refreshed = true;
        findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(findViewById(R.id.list).getVisibility() == View.GONE||findViewById(R.id.list).getHeight() <= 0){
                <do something>
                }
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, EarthquakeActivity.this).forceLoad();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initing a new loader on every refresh, try simply restarting the same loader when you click the refresh button:

```
findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(findViewById(R.id.list).getVisibility() == View.GONE||findViewById(R.id.list).getHeight() <= 0){
                <do something>
            }
            if(getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0) == null) {
                  getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, EarthquakeActivity.this);
            } else {
                getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, EarthquakeActivity.this);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: what is the relation between starting a new loader and showing up of toast twice?

Comment: The fact that a toast is showing twice means onFinishedLoad is being called twice. The fact that onload finished is being called twice might be because your initializing an already initiated loader.

Comment: it should be getSupportLoaderManager instead of getLoaderManager because getLoaderManager is giving an error for the third argument

Comment: If you're using AppCompatActivity the it should be getSupportLoaderManager